# POSTGRESQL: How to display blank for TIMESTAMP column

Tags: postgresql, null, timestamp

I need to display blank when I have NULL in timestamp field, my code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN exp_date IS NULL THEN CAST(' ' AS TIMESTAMP)
ELSE exp_date END
```

But it throws an error. I don't want to display NULL. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast whitespace to a timestamp. "Display" is really up to the application displaying the data. I use PGAdmin 3, and by default that shows NULLs as "blank", though you can configure it to show something else like `<NULL>` for NULLs instead.

The best solution is update your code to display a blank or whatever you want when the field is NULL. Otherwise you could cast the timestamp to TEXT so you can display whatever you want from the PG side:

`SELECT CASE WHEN exp_date IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE exp_date::TEXT END`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COALESCE(exp_date::TEXT,'')
FROM ...
```

The [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function will return the first value that is non-null, which in this case is a blank.

Comment: This won't work as exp_date is a timestamp, you can't COALESCE a timestamp and text.

Comment: Right you are. (worked in my local test db, typo'd the cast in the answer). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: WOW , I like the code; it works on my local DB as well but I used it in another query

Comment: COALESCE is generally going to be faster than CASE statements, but if you aren't doing dozens to thousands of queries per second it might not be noticeable in your environment.